# Spring MVC UI service form submission behind Spring Cloud Zuul

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

The problem is when a form POST happens and then the controller does a redirect it seems that the redirect does not know it is behind Zuul.

Form:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create-something", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getForm(Model model, @CookieValue(value = "XSRF-TOKEN", defaultValue = "none", required=true) String token) {

    model.addAttribute("title", "Create New Something");

    model.addAttribute("_csrf", token);

    return "views/create-something";

}
```

POST:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create-something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute Something something) {

    SomethingClient.createSomething(something);

    return "redirect:" + something.getName() + "/";

}
```

This setup will result in the redirect trying to hit the internal IP of the UI service not the public Zuul URL.

Comment: How did you build this app? I want a Spring MVC front end, talking to a zuul exposed API, preferably in the same JVM (nodes). So curious on the how to?

Comment: @tgkprog Setting this up was fairly simple. Take a look at the Spring Cloud Samples and you should have a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying different approaches I finally settled on a direct URL.  Not sure if there is a better solution but this does work and resolves the above problem.

New POST:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create-something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute Something something) {

    SomethingClient.createSomething(something);

    return "redirect:http://domain.com/ui/" + something.getName() + "/";

}
```

Another thought would be an interceptor.  That felt like added complexity times a large number of UI services.

Comment: Is there a best way to do that ? I have the same issue even though I setup zuul and my web app to use forward header.

Comment: @DamienPolegato Another possibility would be to use a message bus.  With the example above using a property of the domain would probably make this a little more flexible.  Then you would only have to enter the domain within the properties file and not have it populated across all of your controllers.